# Validating user input between two strings?

Tags: java

my code right now checks if they user types in "r" for customer type if not it throws an error message, I want it to also check if the user types in "c" because that's also a valid customer type. I tried using in "else if" statement after the first "if" so i can check if its not r then is it c if not throw an error message but it wont work????

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
        String customerType = sc.next();
        if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type. Try Again ");
        continue;
        }
        else




        System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
        double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

        // get the discount percent
        double discountPercent = 0;
        if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 100)
                discountPercent = 0;
            else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .1;
            else if (subtotal >= 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
        }
        else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
            else
                discountPercent = .3;
        }
        //else

        //{sc.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type. Try Again ");
        //continue;
        //}
        //else}
       // {
          //  discountPercent = .1;
       // }

        // calculate the discount amount and total
        double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
        double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

        // format and display the results
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        System.out.println(
                "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
                "Discount amount:  " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
                "Total:            " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are not throwing error anywhere...

Comment: That else without a proper brace...not sure if that's what you intended.  Either way, could you reduce the scope of this question a bit?

Comment: Agree with @Makoto - reducing the amount of code to the minimum required to demonstrate the error is good practice (and often allows you to solve your own problem, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If I don't missunderstanding your questions, you want validate if the user only input r and c for customer type.

So, just add another condition in your if statement.

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
    {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.print("Enter customer type (r/c): ");
        String customerType = sc.next();

        // VALIDATE ONLY R and C customer type.
        if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type. Try Again ");
        continue;
        }
        else {

        System.out.print("Enter subtotal:   ");
        double subtotal = sc.nextDouble();

        // get the discount percent
        double discountPercent = 0;
        if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 100)
                discountPercent = 0;
            else if (subtotal >= 100 && subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .1;
            else if (subtotal >= 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
        }
        else if (customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            if (subtotal < 250)
                discountPercent = .2;
            else
                discountPercent = .3;
        }
        //else

        //{sc.nextLine();
        //System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type. Try Again ");
        //continue;
        //}
        //else}
       // {
          //  discountPercent = .1;
       // }

        // calculate the discount amount and total
        double discountAmount = subtotal * discountPercent;
        double total = subtotal - discountAmount;

        // format and display the results
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        System.out.println(
                "Discount percent: " + percent.format(discountPercent) + "\n" +
                "Discount amount:  " + currency.format(discountAmount) + "\n" +
                "Total:            " + currency.format(total) + "\n");

        // see if the user wants to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You're providing a huge block of code without any explanation.  It doesn't help illuminate what the actual problem was unless I invested the time to read through both the OP and your code.

Comment: I think the line that was changed is `if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))`

Comment: @Floris : you're right, but it is my mistake to add the explanation..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In these lines of code:

```
if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
{
        sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Error! Invalid Customer Type. Try Again ");
    continue;
}
```

an error is thrown if the input is not an R.  You also don't want an error to be thrown if the input is a T.  So, change 
    if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))

to

```
if (!customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("R") && !customerType.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
```